# Найти численное значение производной функции в точке в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

в среде MATLAB необходимо найти численное значение производной функции в точке.

```
x0 = -10;
syms x;
Func = 2*exp(-5-x)-2.5;
dv = diff(Func, 'x');
Devirative = subs(dv, x, x0);
```

возвращается символьное значение (-2*exp(5)), как его посчитать? не прописывать же вручную.

Answer (score 2):

`df = double(Devirative)` или `df = eval(Devirative)`